# Run multiple services inside one docker container

Tags: docker, containers

I'm new to docker. I just installed it and I have a question about this , it could be duplicated but I can't found a solution by searching all the forums.
Why it's better to use juste one service (apache, PHP, Mysql...) inside one container?

Answer (score 1):

Because the whole point of Docker is to encapsulate a service within a single image, that you then clone to make instances of. You can clone multiple instances and trivially scale out an application - but it's rare that you need to clone every element of the application like that. It's much more useful to be able to widen your web tier, or your database tier separately.

But the major reason is - a container is an instance of an image. If you update your application, you need to build a new image. It's considerably more useful to be able to rebuild and restart subcomponents of the application, for all the reasons it's a nuisance to have to update your server to 'update'.